# Checking what action would be called by a given url string

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.6

In Laravel (5.6) I want to see what route would be called by a given url string. Say the url was "report/sales" I would like to check what function from what controller would be called, eg could be "ReportController@salesreport". It's sort of the opposite of the action() function but I can't find anything like it.

Would be wonderful if anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel doesn't provide a direct means of checking for a Route matching a URI, likely because it [performs multiple assertions](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.6/src/Illuminate/Routing/Matching) for host, method, etc. during matching. Almost all matching uses a Request object for comparison.

The quickest way to use existing functionality is to manually create a `Request` object with the details you wish to match against (HTTP method, URI, etc.). Once you've done that, you can grab the Router and look:

```php
$request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create('/report/sales');

$routes = Route::getRoutes(); // Or, you can get the Router directly, through app(), etc.

try {
    $route = $routes->match($request);

    $action = $route->getActionName();
} catch (\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $e) {
    // No matching route was found.
} catch (\Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MethodNotAllowedException $e) {
    // The URI matches a route for a different HTTP method
}
```

Comment: I didn't try, but if you are in a controller method you might as well reuse the current `$request` object (that should hold the correct url as well) instead of creating a new one?

Comment: I wouldn't, because then you're modifying the current request context. It would no longer be a source of truth. Creating a new request object says "this is a different request".

Answer (score 0):

You could retrive the Router instance through the Container and retrive all routes, then filter the retrived routes to match only the ones that has url attribute equal to the given url string. Finally, pluck the matching controller action for each route.

```php
$routes = app('router')->getRoutes()->getRoutes();
$target = 'report/sales';

$actions = collect($routes)->filter(function($route) use ($target) {
    return $route->uri == $target;
})->pluck('action.controller');

dd($actions);
```

If you only need to get one route only (eg: no routes with the same URL but different verbs), just replace `filter` with `first` to stop at the first matching occurence. As a result you will no longer need pluck, as you will be given a Route instance, not a collection:

```php
$routes = app('router')->getRoutes()->getRoutes();
$target = 'report/sales';

$action = collect($routes)->first(function($route) use ($target) {
    return $route->uri == $target;
})->action['controller'];

dd($action);
```

Comment: This won't be able to match routes with parameters unless you search for the route pattern (e.g. `blog/post/{id}'`) and not the generated URI (`blog/post/34`).

Comment: You are correct, mine was a quick and dirty solution (also building up the collection to filter agains each route wasn't a top-notch option) based on the url he gave as example. Thanks for pointing it out